# common:linkPodReleaseFrameworkIos e: Compilation failed: Assertion failed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I have a problem with archiving(realising my app).

I'm using the following dependency versions:

```
kotlin=1.6.10
ktor=2.0.0-beta-1
kotlinx.datetime=0.2.1
kotlinx.serialization=1.3.2
```

Tried to change versions of Kotlin serialisation plugin, or date time plugin but it hasn't fixed the issue. Any ideas where is the problem?

I'm receiving error:

```
Task :common:linkPodReleaseFrameworkIos
e: Compilation failed: Assertion failed

 * Source files: 
 * Compiler version info: Konan: 1.6.0 / Kotlin: 1.6.0
 * Output kind: FRAMEWORK

e: java.lang.AssertionError: Assertion failed
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.objcexport.MethodBridgeKt.parametersAssociated(MethodBridge.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.objcexport.ObjCExportCodeGeneratorKt.generateKotlinToObjCBridge(ObjCExportCodeGenerator.kt:1029)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.objcexport.ObjCExportCodeGeneratorKt.createReverseAdapter(ObjCExportCodeGenerator.kt:1180)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.objcexport.ObjCExportCodeGeneratorKt.createReverseAdapters(ObjCExportCodeGenerator.kt:1463)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.objcexport.ObjCExportCodeGeneratorKt.createReverseAdapters$getOrCreateFor(ObjCExportCodeGenerator.kt:1404)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.objcexport.ObjCExportCodeGeneratorKt.createReverseAdapters(ObjCExportCodeGenerator.kt:1407)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.objcexport.ObjCExportCodeGeneratorKt.access$createReverseAdapters(ObjCExportCodeGenerator.kt:1)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.objcexport.ObjCExportCodeGenerator.generateTypeAdaptersForKotlinTypes(ObjCExportCodeGenerator.kt:262)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.objcexport.ObjCExportCodeGenerator.generateTypeAdapters(ObjCExportCodeGenerator.kt:289)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.objcexport.ObjCExportCodeGenerator.generate$backend_native_compiler(ObjCExportCodeGenerator.kt:300)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.objcexport.ObjCExport.generate$backend_native_compiler(ObjCExport.kt:103)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor$visitModuleFragment$2.invoke(IrToBitcode.kt:433)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor$visitModuleFragment$2.invoke(IrToBitcode.kt:431)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.runAndProcessInitializers(IrToBitcode.kt:370)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitModuleFragment(IrToBitcode.kt:431)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitModuleFragment(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitModuleFragment(IrToBitcode.kt:204)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitModuleFragment(IrToBitcode.kt:204)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, already described at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49395.

From what I see in this ticket, the problem should be already fixed in Kotlin 1.6.20-M1.
If you can use preview versions in your project, consider trying it as described here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2022/02/kotlin-1-6-20-m1-released/.

Comment: Yes this is it!! Thanks so much!